# Repeat an animation a variable number of times

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation

I was wondering how I can set an animation to repeat. The number of repetitions needs to be determined by a variable. In the following code, the variable `int newPage` should determine how often the animation is repeated.

I tried this, but the animation (which employs a block animation) was only executed once:

```
for (int temp = 1; temp <= newPage; temp++) {
            [self animatePage];
}
```

If I code the following, it works like I want it to, but this is hardcoded (i.e. the animation will be repeated twice) and I can't see a way of how to change the number of how often this animation is executed in code and according to my variable newPage:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0
                      delay:0.1
            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
             animations:^{[self animatePage];}
             completion:^(BOOL finished){[self animatePage];}];
```

I'd be very grateful for suggestions of how to repeat the same animation without having to hardcode the number of times I want this animation to be repeated.

---

EDIT:

I tried to implement the following code, but only one animation will actually be carried out:

```
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0
                          delay:1
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{

                         [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:2];
                         [self animatePage];

                     }
                     completion:nil];
```

Comment: You know, I'm fairly sure "removeAllAnimations" is what you're after here - see answer below, cheers!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Had the same problem - you were missing an an'UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat'

This should work:

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0
                      delay:1
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                 animations:^{
                     [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:2]; // **This should appear in the beginning of the block**
                     [self animatePage];

                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

Did the trick for me.

Comment: So odd that not putting that modified at the beginning of your animation block results in infinite repeating.

Answer (score 8):

Did you try to set the repeatCount? `+ (void)setAnimationRepeatCount:(float)repeatCount`

I've tried the following code block, and it definitely repeats 2x for me (l was a UITextView that was scaled up by 2x in X dir and 3X in Y dir):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2 
delay:0.1 
options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn 
animations:^{ [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:2]; 
l.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2,3); } completion:nil];
```

Comment: No. Good idea! But how would I need to implement this? Sorry if this is basic, but I'm rather new to all of this.

Comment: @DavidNeiss: I've just tried this, but it doesn't work. If I set it to 2, only one animation will be executed. I updated the code above accordingly, so you can see how I tried to implement it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @n.evermind: Have you tried `setAnimationRepeatCount:` _before_ `animateWithDuration:`, i.e., not in the `animations` block?

Comment: @Josh Caswell: No, because the docs say that you should call it from within: "This method does nothing if called from outside of an animation block. You can use this method in conjunction with either the block-based methods or the begin/commit methods for defining an animation block. ... If you pass the UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat option to the animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion: method without setting an explicit repeat count, the animation repeats indefinitely. If you want the animation to repeat a finite number of times, call this method from inside your block."

Comment: @Josh Caswell: I actually solved it: The other animation I was calling was longer than the animation duration I specified... my fault.

Comment: @n.evermind: Glad to hear it! Please consider posting your actual solution as an answer and accepting that, rather than just leaving the solution in a comment and giving the checkmark to an arbitrary answer. That will be much more helpful to future readers.

Answer (score 2):

the reason you arent seeing but one animation is that due to the fact that you are calling the animation from a loop in the same runloop, resuting in the last call winning (one animation)

instead of calling  `[self animatePage]`, try calling

```
[self performSelector:@selector(animatePage) withObject:nil afterDelay:.1 *temp];
```

this will create your calls on separate threads.

you may need to play with the delay interval

Comment: I see what you mean, but this doesn't work with short intervals. I really need 0.1 and your suggested line of code only works with 1.0 and above (which is too slow). Thanks for your clarification, though!

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the hiccup between animations, use keyframes. I wrote an extension that works on anything conforming to UIView (which is a ton of visual elements)

**Swift 4:**

```
import UIKit
extension UIView{
    func rotate(count: Float, _ complete: @escaping ()->()) {
        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0, options: [.repeat], animations: {
            //to rotate infinitely, comment the next line
            UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount(count)
            //rotate the object to 180 degrees
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.5/1.0, animations: {
                self.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (CGFloat(Double.pi)))
            })
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.5/1.0, animations: {
                //rotate the object from 180 to 360 degrees
                self.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (CGFloat(Double.pi * 2)))
            })
        }, completion:{ _ in
            complete()
        })
    }
}
```

To call it anywhere in the app:

```
view.rotate() { /*do after*/ }
```